# Foreign key mysql set null

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы: message и user.

```
`user` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role` enum('client','bot') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

message CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `message_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_message_user1` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_message_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Все внимание на SET NULL во внешнем ключе. Так работать не будет, потому что нужно разрешить NULL для поля `message.user_id`. Но я не могу его разрешить, потому что связан с primary ключем `user.user_id`, который не может быть NULL.

Вопрос: как в конкретной ситуации заставить mysql делать ON DELETE SET NULL?

Comment: А зачем вам составной первичный ключ? Уберите `user_id` из PK. И все получится.  
ЗЫ Это совет не в смысле как обойти систему, а в смысле, что в первичном составном ключе на самом деле нет никакого смысла.

Comment: pk user_id создает мне mysql workbench, когда я убираю его, он показывает мне, что внешняя связь неполноценная. Но теперь все стало понятно, я думал, что not null из внешней таблицы, а оказываеться из-за pk user_id из таблицы message.